# Icon to indicate a span of time

Tags: icon, interface-design, information-graphics, information-design

I have a mobile app interface with a list of dates and notes:

- Sep 5 - No longer contagious
- Sep 6 - Can return to school
- ...
- Sep 9 - Back to normal

Right now I am **using an ellipsis to indicate a gap in days, or time passing** between notes. The problem I'm seeing is that this is commonly used to indicate that the user can tap for "more" info, and users are trying to do this. I see problems with other icons as well:

- Clock: indicates time itself, not a *span* of time
- Hourglass: indicates waiting

**What can I use to illustrate the passage of a few days time?**

Comment: A little down arrow?

Comment: That honestly might be the ticket

Comment: I think the problem is that anything that looks like an icon will look like a button and will have people trying to tap on it. Has to look like background structure if you don't want people tapping on it - more in updated answer below.

Comment: You could also play with some form of grouping. Where events that have less than 24 hours between them are closer to each other and then after a 24 hour period if you do something again it'll create a new group. In between groups your could use a border, horizontal rule, different title, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe?

[image]

or this

[image]

or this

[image]

the "Timer" icon may also reflect time span

[image]

Just the ideas...

*By the way, I would not recommend to indicate the exact amount of time by the icon, like: 1h, 1d, 2d, etc. The graphics should only represent the meaning, like "passed time".*

Comment: The simplicity of the final one works for me stylistically. Maybe if it were using the same graphics as the greeny/blue orb it'd be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Re-reading this, particularly that the problem is users trying to tap for more info - *any* icon is likely to look like a button that can be pressed. Icons almost by definition are intended to attract attention and look like something functional: whereas you want something that looks like background.

So given that, I think it has to look like a joining line - background and structure, not foreground. How about something like

```
[NOTE]---|-|---[NOTE]---|---[NOTE]---|-|-|-|-|---[NOTE]
```

...but where the vertical lines (one for each day passed) are very thin and close together so there's not too big a gap?

The principle behind this suggestion is: to carry information but not look like a button or interaction point, it has to carry information while looking like part of the background structure - not foreground. It has to be something people glance past, not something people are drawn to look at directly.

---

**Original answer:** if it *was* okay for it to look like an icon (therefore, potentially like a button)...

Since you're specifically looking at days, there are two common conventions you can use:

- Something often used in films, TV, comics etc to signify passing days: crossing off days on a calendar, mixed with...
- ...that common, familiar type of calendar icon ([taken from the Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/noun/calendar/#icon-No404)):

[image]

...but of course you need to make it clear that it's the passing of days that is the focus, not the calendar itself.  You could draw a calendar so the calendar itself is clearly recognisable but background, and crossed off days are the foreground, something like this:

[image]

Depending on how much space you have, you could potentially have different icons for smaller and larger amounts of time passing:

[image]

...but don't get carried away! Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

![you can try this type or stop clock type or Bell like icon..but present it like notclickable..i will come under the way u presented...

Comment: This has a very cyclical connotation, I think

Comment: How do you present an icon as non-clickable on mobile app?